# Transform quadratic form into canonical form.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms, canonical-transformation

The polynomial is given: $f=x_1x_2-x_2x_3$. I have to construct a matrix for this form before and after a reduction to the canonical form.

I have a difficulty even at the first step, the matrix that I get is like this:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1/2 & 0 \\1/2 & 0 &-1/2 \\0 & -1/2 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

So, following to that I compute the $\det(A-\lambda\cdot I)=0$ and get eigenvalues $\lambda_1=0$ and $\lambda_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.  (The way I calculated the eigenvalues was just by computing the said determinant and equal the found expression to zero.)

So, what should I do next?

Comment: Why don't you tell us what is "canonical form" of a quadratic form. Do you mean to express $\;f\;$ as a sum of squares?

Comment: @DonAntonio Well I read that a quadratic form is written in canonical way if it doesn't have multipliers $x_{ij}$ where $i\neq j$. For example, canonical way in two dimensions would be $$\lambda_1\cdot {x^2}_1+ \lambda_2\cdot x^2_2}$$. Maybe in english it has a different name?

Comment: There are many questions to be asked about the context. Are you working over the real numbers ? Are you expected to give an explicit basis change for the diagonalization ? Is the diagonalization supposed to be done in an orthogonal basis, or is any basis change allowed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1/2 & 0 \\1/2 & 0 &-1/2 \\0 & -1/2 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

$S_1 =0+0+0 = 0$, $S_2 = -\frac{1}{4}+0-\frac{1}{4} = -\frac{1}{2}$ , $S_3 = \det(A) = 0$

$$\lambda^3-S_1\lambda^2+S_2\lambda -S_3 = 0 \implies \lambda^3 - 0 - \frac{1}{2}\lambda-0=0$$

$$\lambda(\lambda^2 -\frac{1}{2}) = 0 \implies \lambda=0,\frac{1}{\sqrt2},\frac{-1}{\sqrt2}$$

So, the reference diagonal matrix is ,

> $$D = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt2} &0 \\0 & 0 & \frac{-1}{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}$$

Let $$Y = \begin{bmatrix}y_1 \\y_2 \\y_3\end{bmatrix}$$

So, the required canonical form is,

> $$C = Y^TDY= 0y_1^2 +\frac{1}{\sqrt2}y_2^2-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}y_3^2$$

---

You've found $X_1$ and $X_3$ correctly.

But there's a mistake with your $X_2$ .

$X_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1\sqrt2 \\1 \\-1\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}$

Normalized vectors: $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0 \\1\end{bmatrix}$,$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}1\sqrt2 \\1 \\-1\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}$,$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}-1\sqrt2 \\1 \\1\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}$

$N = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{1}{\sqrt2}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\0 &1 &1\\1 &-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}$

$N^T = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0&1\\\frac{1}{\sqrt2} &1 &-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt2} &1&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}$

Now, $$AN = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1/2 & 0 \\1/2 & 0 &-1/2 \\0 & -1/2 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{1}{\sqrt2}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\0 &1 &1\\1 &-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix} =\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\0&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\0&-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$$

$$D = N^TAN = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0&1\\\frac{1}{\sqrt2} &1 &-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt2} &1&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\0&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\0&-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 &0\\0&\sqrt2&0\\0&0&-\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}$$

Thus,

> $$D = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 &0\\0&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}&0\\0&0&-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: So, does that mean that canonical way would simply be an expression $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}y^2_2-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}y^2_3$? Or did I misunderstood smth?

Comment: Yes, as the first Eigen-value is zero!

Comment: Still I have a question, I had a task to transform a quadratic form into canonical using the main theorem, is it any different than I did ( By simply constructing a matrix and then founding eigenvalues?) Also, other user said something about eigenvectors, I don't need those in order to find  a canonical form, right?

Comment: From the examination point of view, if the question has to be answered in detail, then you have to find the Eigen vectors, normalize them and find the diagonal matrix. If it is to be answered in short, you can directly put the Eigen values along the diagonal and zeroes at the remaining places. So, it depends on how the question has to be answered.

Comment: Here I have computed the eigenvectors for all three eigenvalues: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3245729/finding-eigenvectors-and-canonical-form?noredirect=1#comment6675318_3245729. How do I find a diagonal matrix after I had normalise those vectors?

Comment: $D = N^TAN$ and $N$ is the normalized matrix found by dividing each Eigen vector by its magnitude and placing each vector along its columns. For example, the normalized form of the 1st Eigenvector is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$. Now do similarly for the remaining 2 vectors and place them along the columns to find $N$, then find $N^T$ and $D$

Comment: I think I did something wrong, the matrix N I computed as: N =$\left[\begin{matrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \end{matrix}\right]$ The product of multiplication $AN$ is $\left[\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 &  -1 & -\frac{1}{2}\end{matrix}\right]$ When I do a final multiplication $N^T A$ the product isn't a diagonal matrix, but some random matrix with lots of $\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ It should be a diagonal matrix, right?

Comment: I've solved it and added in the answer, you may check it :)

Comment: Thank you so much, now I understand how to do these sort of exercises. :)

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I have the very last question, when I express the eigenvectors from matrices with corresponding $\lambda$ values, do I need to choose one coordinate to be equal to 1 or I can choose whatever value?

Comment: You can choose any non-zero value, because corresponding to each Eigen-value, there exist infinitely many Eigen-vectors